# Individual Form Params when POST data is split

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, formtastic

I'm trying to access a date variable from a form individually to the other variables. The form is a formtastic plugin form. The issue I am facing is that the date is a three-part dropdown and simply doing params[:friend][:born_on] doesn't seem to be doing the trick as it returns NULL.

Here is my parameters output;

> Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create", "action"=>"create", "authenticity_token"=>"6+PyuqUNQySe29iEF69PIFvv6DOie5bp4jZAcRva85c=", "controller"=>"friends", "friend"=>{"born_on(1i)"=>"1973", "born_on(2i)"=>"3", "born_on(3i)"=>"5", "is_female"=>"false", "last_name"=>"Smith", "first_name"=>"John"}}

I want to use the variable to set another method; event.happening_on

Any help is appreciated- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason params[:friend][:born_on] is not returning anything is because that's not the name of the parameter.

It looks like the values you're looking for is one of: `params[:friend]["born_on(1i)"]`, `params[:friend]["born_on(2i)"]`, or `params[:friend]["born_on(3i)"]`. Which corresponds to what looks like, year, month and day respectively.